# HTML5 video recording and capture - .record is not a function

Tags: html, video-streaming, webrtc

I'm trying to use WebRTC to upload a video to a ASP page.

Here is the page load script:

```
window.navigator = window.navigator || {};
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia       ||
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.mozGetUserMedia    ||
                         null;

if (navigator.getUserMedia === null) {
       //Unsupported.
      } else {


        document.getElementById('button-play-gum').addEventListener('click', function() {
          // Capture user's audio and video source
          navigator.getUserMedia({
            video: true,
            audio: true
          },
          function(stream) {
            videoStream = stream;
            // Stream the data
            video.src = createSrc(stream);
            video.play();
          },
          function(error) {
            console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code);
          });
        });

      }
```

This works fine, and I can see my camera input on screen.

Now I created a button which calls the following line.
When calling this line:

```
streamRecorder = videoStream.record();
```

I get this error:

**videoStream.record is not a function**

Any ideas about this?

Comment: Which Browser are you using? There is no method `record` in MediaStream.

Comment: Both Chrome, IE and Edge, latest versions.

Comment: @KobyDouek yeah, recording media is not that simple, except in the case of firefox([MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder))

Comment: also, don't think IE supports getUserMedia\

Comment: @KobyDouek could you able to find a solution to your problem? Please post your answer, I am running into similar problem - primarily for Edge browser.